# Bounds on discrete convolution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, convolution

Let 
\begin{align}
a_n=   cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2} n\right)n^{- \frac{1}{2}n +\frac{1}{2} }
\end{align}

and let 
\begin{align}
c_{2n}= \sum_{m=0}^{2n} a_m a_{2n-m}
\end{align}

Note that the above is an operation of discrete convolution

**Question 1** : Can we establish that 
\begin{align}
 \lim_{n \to \infty } c_{2n}=0
\end{align}

**Question 2:** If the about is true can we also establish how fast does  $c_{2n}$ go to zero by showing bounds on $|c_{2n}|$?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Cauchy product :

$$\sum c_n = \left(\sum a_n\right)^2 = \left(\sum \frac{i^n +(-i)^n}{2} n^{- \frac{1}{2}n +\frac{1}{2} }\right)^2$$

which converges, thus $ c_n \longrightarrow 0$ .

Comment: Thank you. Very nice proof. Two questions: How did you get a $(-1)^n$ inside the last sum?  Also, any idea how to bound $|c_n|???

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake, it's $\cos\left(n\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \frac{i^n +(-i)^n}{2}$. For the bounding, let me think of it.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know if you have something.